# How to load local assets on window.open with CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, chromium

Using React Portal I created a component that opens a popup window with `window.open`, loads all of the  tags from the original window's head, and renders the children inside that window's body.
Let's call it `<PopupWindow/>`

Code for loading the CSS was taken from:
https://gist.github.com/davidgilbertson/ed3c8bb8569bc64b094b87aa88bed5fa#file-copystyles-js

The problem I was having is that fonts and other assets weren't loaded to the new window.

I had 2 non-optimal solutions for the issue:

1. Put all required assets in the public folder - This is discouraged by CRA as they recommend that assets should be imported in the code.
2. I created a router in my `<App/>` component that either routes to the original app or an empty fragment

   ```
   export const App: React.FC = () => {
       return (
           <BrowserRouter>
               <Switch>
                   <Route path="/popup">
                       <></>
                   </Route>
                   <Route path="/">
                       <OriginalApp />
                   </Route>
               </Switch>
           </BrowserRouter>
       );
   };
   ```

   And then in my `<PopupWindow/>` component I call:
   `` window.open(`/popup`, 'popup', windowOptionsStr) ``

   This doesn't feel right that I have to refactor my whole app to support this popup component.

**Note**: This is done in an Electron App. So it only runs in Chromium and popups are not blocked.

Is there a better, working and recommended way to load assets to a new window?